# Upgrade Apache CORS no longer works

Tags: angularjs, apache

I just upgraded from Apache 2.2 -> 2.4  Took a little bit of work to get PHP and SSL running again, but now i have one problem i can't figure out... CORS

I have in my virtual host

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

but i keep getting an error saying

```
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I can't seem to find anything that is preventing this from working. Clearly i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualHost is probably no longer being used due to your distros package creating/restoring a default virtual host that covers your customized one up.

Sometimes this happens if your systems own notion of its hostname is what you use for ServerName in your custom vhost.

I'd suggest setting a dummy ServerName in the default vhost created by your distros configuration, or removing it entirely.

You can review a summary of your vhost with `apachectl -S`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was similar issue, when updating the package the new .conf file disabled .htaccess directives.